# TikZ and the handling of some key-value pairs in `\NewDocumentCommands`

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

When defining parameters for the `\draw` command in a `\NewDocumentCommand` setting `[help lines]` is rejected, as are some other arguments, for example `[ultra thin]` etc., but `[lime,thin]` etc. are OK. Could there be something askew in the handling of the `Expl3 key-value` interface in `TikZ`? Evidentally, no such problems occur if using the `LaTeX2 \newcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 28 March 2017
%=======================
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\myGrid{O{4}}
  {
    %\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (#1,#1); => compiler ERROR
    \draw [lime,thin] (0,0) grid (#1,#1);
  } 
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myGrid [10]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, in the `expl3` regime, your spaces are ignored, i.e. `help lines` is seen as `helpline` which is most likely undefined. Your command does not make any use of `expl3` features, so why do you use `\ExplSyntaxOn` there -- the `\NewDocumentCommand`etc. macro do not need it all (as front-end to `expl3`)

Comment: In that situation you would need `help~lines` (or `help ~ lines`, if you want it to look a bit more spaced up), because “spaces” are input with `~` inside expl3 code.

Comment: @Manuel: Yes, but since there are **some** pgfkeys with spaces inside, it will get tedious to preserve for them with `~` inside

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, no doubt. I even asked to ignore spaces in expl3 keys as a result related of this problem with pgfkeys. But if it's for a few keys in a macro definition, then there's no problem with issuing `~`.

Comment: @Manuel: Yes, for some few occurences this is perfectly alright.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer Running my `\NewDocumentCommand` outside `\ExplSyntaxOn ... Off` would indeed solve the problem, if the `\draw ...` command were the only thing that's in it! In following the stated intentions of a `Minimal Working Example` I have become used to removing everything except the single item that causes a problem prior to submitting any question to the `TeX.SX` - rest assured I would not bother writing a macro as barren as `\myGrid` other than to serve as an `MWE`. So, assuming there is stuff in there that does require `Expl3`, is there a workaround?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer On perusing your conversation with @Manuel I find inserting `~` and using `help~lines`, `ultra~thin` etc. is a fix. Thanks.

Comment: Ti*k*Z + Expl3 really do not mix at all well. Given that `\NewDocumentCommand` is only really supposed to provide a wrapper to deal with user input, can't you split this stuff out so that the Ti*k*Z code in in the normal package environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tilde is the "space" in the expl3 language, so whenever you need a real space, e.g., in strings or in keys as in your example you need to add a "space" which inside expl3 regime is visually looking like a tilde.

Now there are good arguments for making the normal space ignored and once you are used~to~write~strings~like~this~ or~ this~ it isn't that tedious (and much easier to correct if forgotten compared to finding the issue caused by a missing percent in LaTeX2e code).

Of course if you have to write many strings in your code (or the tilde is not easily usable with your keyboard) then it is a little less convenient, but on the whole that convention of expl3 has helped a lot to get much more readable code and much less errors due to forgotten % characters in important places (that result in tiny extra spaces in the output that are hard to track --- much harder than astringwhereforsomereasonthespacesaremissing.

Comment: One should also point out that `~` in the replacement text of a macro is normalized to a space token with character code 32 and category code 10, so when the TikZ scanning takes place, spaces are found where they should. Moreover, `~` is not removed at end of lines.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by this. However, I'm not entirely conviced the other way either. ***Except for PGF/Ti*k*Z.*** There it really is much trickier with Expl3 syntax active and I'd advise avoiding it, myself.

Comment: I have learnt to appreciate the `~`, slowly but surely. It certainly has fixed the problem here. Much obliged.
While I am sure that @cfr makes a valid point when advising to separate the "normal package environment" from Expl3 and put TikZ stuff into  the former, the argument goes over my head technically. I pretend that `Expl3`, which provides me with the`\NewDocumentCommand` and similar document level commands as well as the many functions introduced in the various references, is all there is and continue to refuse to look under the hood.